# IHttpHandler with .Net 6/7 and IIS

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, iis-10

We have a custom IHttpHandler that is responsible for the incomming request in IIS.
we have override

```
public interface IHttpHandler
{
    bool IsReusable { get; }
    void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context);
}
```

We want upgrade with .net 6 or 7 but the namespace System.Web.IHttpHandler doesn't exist and
how install .net 6 or 7 under IIS ?

What's the best way ?

Comment: have you considered to [convert them into middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-7.0)?

Comment: not again ... is it the best way ? IIS 10 with .Net 6 is it possible ? thanks

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. There's no `IHttpHandler` because *it's no longer needed*. What does `not again` mean? If you already got that answer, why do you ask again? What are you trying to implement and why isn't a simple `app.Use(async (context, next) =>{...})` enough? Instead of interface registration, you got a single method call

Comment: @Ig0173 lets simplify the problem. .Net Framework is a tractor while .Net Core is a is a car. you wouldn't fit a tractor wheels on a car and vice versa. they are similar but not the exact same. hence, getting 1-to-1 replacement is not possible on some cases.

Comment: Migrating a handler to a middleware is the only option and it's not that difficult.

Comment: The "why" matters. Perhaps the feature is available out of the box already, and not just for IIS. Perhaps you need to reimplement it. Perhaps it's just a function or configuration setting now, so all you have to do is set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to extend IIS functionality, then you have to stay on .NET Framework.

> ASP.NET Core middleware is a different approach and not tightly integrated with IIS pipeline.

Comment: why ? Net6 is fast and the future .... we can't migrate ?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? `IHttpHandler` is how you implemented that in the past, not the end goal itself. .NET 6 is .NET *Core*, an entirely new and by now, not that new, runtime

Comment: @lg0173 For IIS, either you write a native module or stay on .NET Framework 4.x. .NET Core was never an option there, so why bother?

Comment: @panagiotis : I was just wondering for now